# Is it possible to access DOM information from embedded file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

My objective: add a way for users to print attached files that are linked to a report when printing the report.

I am trying to do it this way so I can embed them and print it all in one file(users mostly use print to pdf) so I would like to have an embedded object that is the exact height it needs for the document so there is no scroll bar and the embeded items are appended and viewable in the same file.

I have found that with Chrome, when pdfs are embedded there is html information that I could use to do this, but I have no idea how to access it from the parent page.

Below are some screenshots of an example in w3 schools tryit editor. the object I need to access is the div #sizer because it is the height the window needs to be to hold the pdf with no overflow.

[image: This is the example of the data that the PDF viewer plugin sends for the embedded pdf, and I need a way to query the style info for #sizer]

[image: This is a W3 schools example of the embedded pdf, but trying to get any html information from the iframe is not seeming to work even if there is html showing in the inspect bar]

I have tried a lot of different jquery selectors in order to try this but continue to get "undefined" as an output for all of the selectors I try.

I have read some documentation about content scripts, but am not sure how to use them or if it would solve my problem. I have also looked at using PDF.js but it hasn't worked so far.

If anyone knows if this is possible any information would be awesome.
If anyone knows that this is completely impossible, please let me know so I can go about this a different way.

Comment: Learn about the same-origin policy.  That is completely impossible.

Comment: You may access the iframe with jQuery by using `.contents()`, e.g. `$("iframe").first().contents().find("embed")`. It will be hard, however, to parse the referenced pdf-file in it.

Comment: I can find the iframe without a problem, but once it gets to where <embed> is thats pretty much where jquery selectors seem to stop working, it won't grab any of the html inside the embed, it seems to only be viewable by the plugin

Comment: and @SLaks same origin policy isnt a problem, the pdf is coming from the same domain as the page, the w3 schools is only an example of where i need to select inside the plugin

Comment: But the extension which renders the HTML isn't in the same domain.  I don't think that will work.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i was wondering. I wasn't sure if there was a library or some built in function that allowed a webpage to get data from a plugin that is being used in the page (you would think so, but it seems not)

Comment: PDF.js will allow you to parse binary PDF data and extract page sizes. (Native plugins are trying to not expose this information) PDF.js will also allow you to paint pages to the canvas (you may need to create bigger canvas and scale it to fit on the printed page to avoid blur). Not sure if knowing/using of jQuery will help you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by going a separate route, I removed it from the HTML before I made a pdf.